# Finding the Asymptotic Curves of a Given Surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, surfaces

I have to find the asymptotic curves of the surface given by $$z = a \left( \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \right),$$ for constant $a \neq 0$.

I guess that what was meant by that statement is that surface $S$ can be locally parametrized by $$X(u,v) = \left( u, v, a \left( \frac{u}{v} + \frac{u}{v} \right) \right).$$  Do you think that my parametrization is correct (meaning that I read the description of the surface correctly), and do you know of a more convenient parametrization?

Assuming that parametrization, I derived the following ($E$, $F$, $G$, are the coefficients of the first fundamental form; $e$, $f$, $g$ are coefficients of the second fundamental form; $N$ is the normal vector to surface $S$ at a point; these quantities are all functions of local coordinates $(u,v)$):

$$E = 1 + a^2 \left( \frac{1}{v} - \frac{v}{u^2} \right)^2,$$ 
$$F = -\frac{a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^2}{u^3 v^3},$$
$$G = 1 + a^2 \left( \frac{1}{u} - \frac{u}{v^2} \right)^2.$$

$$N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{E G - F^2}} \left( a \left( \frac{v}{u^2}-\frac{1}{v} \right), a \left( \frac{u}{v^2}-\frac{1}{u} \right), 1 \right).$$

$$X_{u,u} = \left( 0,0, \frac{2 a v}{u^3} \right), X_{u,v} = \left( 0,0, -a \left( \frac{1}{u^2} + \frac{1}{v^2} \right) \right), X_{v,v} = \left( 0, 0, \frac{2 a u}{v^3} \right).$$

$$e = \frac{2 a v}{u^3 \sqrt{E G - F^2}},$$
$$f = - \frac{a (\frac{1}{u^2} + \frac{1}{v^2})}{\sqrt{E G - F^2}},$$
$$g = \frac{2 a u}{v3 \sqrt{E G - F^2}}.$$

Thus, the Gaussian curvature (from these calculations) is:
$$K = -\frac{a^2 u^4 v^4 (u^2 - v^2)^2}{(u^4 v^4 + 
  a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^2 (u^2 + v^2))^2}.$$

And the mean curvature would be:
$$H = \frac{a u^3 v^3 (u^4 + v^4)}{(u^4 v^4 + a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^2 (u^2 + v^2))^{3/2
 }}.$$

So, the principal curvatures are:
$$k_{\pm} = H \pm \sqrt{H^2 - K} = a u^2 v^2 \frac{u v (u^4 + v^4) \pm \sqrt{(u^2 + v^2) (a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^4 + u^2 v^2 (u^6 + v^6))}}{(u^4 v^4 + a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^2 (u^2 + v^2))^{3/2}}.$$

In order to find the asymptotic curves, but trying to avoid the differential equation, I was hoping to find the angles $\theta (u,v)$ such that the normal curvature would always be $0$.  In other words I was trying:
$0 = k_n = k_{+} \cos{(\theta)}^2 + k_{-} \sin{(\theta)}^2$, and solving for $\theta$.

Assuming sufficient niceness, this calculate would result in: $$(u v (u^4 + v^4) + \sqrt{(u^2 + v^2) (a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^4 + u^2 v^2 (u^6 + v^6))}) \cos{(\theta)}^2 + (u v (u^4 + v^4) - \sqrt{(u^2 + v^2) (a^2 (u^2 - v^2)^4 + u^2 v^2 (u^6 + v^6))}) \sin{(\theta)}^2$$

First of all, is this approach (solving for $\theta$ rather than solving the differential equation) valid? If it is, after I find that angle $\theta$, determined by location $(u,v)$ on $S$, what more work do I have to do? How do I find the equations for the asymptotic curves based on this angle?

If this whole method was for naught, how does one solve the differential equation. in this case, of: $$e (u')^2 + 2f u' v' + g (v')^2 = 2a v^4 (u')^2 - 2a u^3 v^3 \left( \frac{1}{u^2} + \frac{1}{v^2} \right)u' v' + 2a u^4 (v')^2 = 0?$$ (Again, assuming sufficient niceness.)

(See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762195/differential-equation-for-the-asymptotic-directions-of-a-given-surface)

Thank you!

Comment: A good effort! I would only suggest you to look at the [picture](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=curvature+z%3D%28x%2Fy+%2B+y%2Fx%29) that reveals that the solutions seem to be straight lines. In fact, you can always rescale the $z$-axis so that your $a$ can be eliminated from most of the calculations.

Comment: Another idea that comes from [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticCurve.html) combined with that [picture](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=curvature+z%3D%28x%2Fy+%2B+y%2Fx%29) is that in the polar coordinates the computations would simplify.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I intuited that they were straight lines, but I still have to prove it.

Comment: @kevin I edited a bit of your post in LaTeX and also added three parentheses in the Gaussian, mean and principal curvatures. Can you check I added them right?

Comment: It looks good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much time for elaborating now, but you definitely can do this yourself (feel free to add your own answer).

Just observe that substitutions $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ to $z = a \left( x/y + y/x \right)$ turn this equation to $z = \tfrac{a}{\cos \theta \cdot \sin \theta}$ which clearly does not depend on $r$. This means that for each $\theta$ the ray $\theta = const$, $r>0$ lies on the surface. Now you can use Corollary 18.6. from Chapter 18 of A.Gray, E.Abbena and S.Salamon "[Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=owEj9TMYo7IC)" stating that "*A straight line that is contained in a regular surface is necessarily an asymptotic curve*".

Alternatively you may try to use the differential equation for asymptotic curves from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AsymptoticCurve.html).

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic lines for a Monge patch X[x,y] has a simple form. Primes on arc.

$ r\, x' ^2 + 2 \,s\, x'y' + t \, y' ^2 = 0 $ where $(r,t,s)$ are second partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Proper sign to be considered for scalars after coming so far with normal curvature. For a negatively curved (Gauss curvature $K<0$ ) surface

$ k_n = -k_{+} \cos^2{\theta} + k_{-} \sin^2{\theta} = 0 $  and for real $\theta$,

$ \tan{\theta} = \sqrt {(k_{+} /  k_{-})} $

For example, asymptotic lines on rotationally symmetric pseudospheres ($ K= -1/a^2 $ ) obey Sine-Gordon on Chebychev net with $2 \theta = 2 \psi,$ angle between asymptotic lines:

$ a\, k_1 = - \tan \psi,  a\, k_2 = \cot \psi, \tan{\psi} = \sqrt {(k_{1} /  k_{2})}. $

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I believe this surface can be described by two networks of lines. ( Shown in Red and Cyan). Make the substitution $nt$ for $u$ , and separately $nt$ for $t$ ,
so that the new parametrization might look like : $<t,nt,a(1/n + n/1)> $ and/or $<nt,t,a(1/n+ n)>$ these are the asymptotic lines. Then switch the sign of n to pick up the surface below the z axis. I've used $n$ as an integer , but every line in the surface chosen in this way is an asymptotic curve, and a geodesic.

(Added a guess for the solution of the equations based on a study of the surface.)

Comment: I upvoted because of your pretty picture.

Comment: The picture is cool but how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: The picture is very nice, but could you advise the calculations?

Comment: The picture is nice, but this doesn't answer his question. Consider adding explanations.